# Stuck on HTML/CSS Styling

Tags: html, css

I made a three-split layout for my about page. It shows fine when I test it locally:

[When I open the about.php locally http://puu.sh/9mb2s/4fce94e621.png](http://puu.sh/9mb2s/4fce94e621.png)

However, when I upload it to my webserver, it doesn't seem like my webhost can figure out where to place the images; only one image appears:

http://puu.sh/9mbfB/1abdba1567.png

I can't seem to figure it out; do any of you have an idea on how I can solve this?

Link to the live webpage: http://jiggelliee.com/about.php

Comment: Jiggelliee..*giggles*...you need to add some code...

Comment: *"Do any of you have any idea how I can solve this?"* - Keep at it, you'll eventually get it right.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24127016/edit) your question to include your code. Something else that might be problematic; if your buttons are images, did you remember to upload the images to the server?

Comment: But why does it show just fine when I open the file locally? This makes no sense for me. I have tried re-uploading the folder containing all the files I use for local testing. But still no luck

Comment: @user3709018 not sure, give us a link for the live webpage as well as show use your styling. You should also check your image links. That is most likely your issue if you are using images

Comment: add your code into the question!

Comment: Sorry, forgot the website link: http://jiggelliee.com/about.php

Comment: Dude he said code not a link your bound to get negatives

Comment: @nol Well, I cant really add all the HTML and CSS into the question, would take to much space. the source code is open, so feel free to inspect

Comment: @Riskbreaker Well, please read all the comments before you talk. "Adjit" asked for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well it looks like your path is not there I just went on your code:

http://jiggelliee.com/img/buttons/about/hello.png

this one looks fine:

http://jiggelliee.com/img/buttons/about/Schedule.png

NExt time use console and see what your issue is...

it looks like the path is wrong:

```
#hellobutton {
background: url("img/buttons/about/hello.png") center center no-repeat;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It's more commentary on the OP's post...

Comment: well that is the answer he needs to add the correct path or its missing...

Comment: Thank you @riskbreaker ! I sloved my problem now. I used an "h" instead of a Capitalised "H" in my style.css